# Crawler could not communicate with the server in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, 2016, crawling

I have farm where I have two application with search servers. It is stretched farm and unfortunately one data center is down since few days. So this is what I see when I access search service application:

[image]

I would expect that it won't impact my search as another application server is fully operational. 
Unfortunately when I go to Crawl log I see only errors with information that crawler could not communicate with the server.

My question is why crawler is trying to use wrong server and how can I make it work?
I wasn't able to find any valuable article describing this topic. Do you have any tips regarding this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check does the site properly resolves from the crawler server (even by simply opening the IE or using PING) to see to what IP the url resolves. You might have some entries in the HOST file. If host file is OK you will need to talk to the Network team to figure out why the traffic is routed to the failed Data Centre.

Comment: Currently everything works fine as second data center is up and running. Nevertheless I would like to figure out why it was not working. I checked hosts file on both application servers. I see that they both have the same entries which route web application to one frontend server (the one which was not available). Could it have any impact on crawler? If that's correct should we set routing on application server to the frontend server within the same data center?

Comment: 1. Yes it will impact the crawler as it will always try to crawl this content via this server. 2. There might have been design decision why it crawls the other datacentre (reduce the workload in the DC1?) hard to say without knowing more. Sometimes you make one of your app server an FE server just for crawler. You might consider to change the binding in host file into the load balanced IP this way you will not hit that problem in the future. I will add the part about host file as answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check does the site properly resolves from the crawler server (even by simply opening the IE or using PING) to see to what IP the url resolves. You might have some entries in the HOST file that point it to the front end server in failed DC.

Comment: You were right. We have modified hosts file, so right now each application server will route to the frontend server within the same data center. Thanks a lot :)